# Changing opacity for KML with linked icon, fetched by leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, kml

I have been struggling with setting the proper opacity in the icon image linked to .kml file, which is next implemented to the Leaflet map.

I used the leaflet-kml plugin based here:

https://github.com/windycom/leaflet-kml

and after attachment of the `L.KML.js` my code looks like this:

```
 var track

    var kml = fetch('Coventry.kml')
      .then( res => res.text() )
      .then( kmltext => {

            // Create new kml overlay
            parser = new DOMParser();
            kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext,"text/xml");
            track = new L.KML(kml);
            //console.log(kml)

            //const track = new L.KML(kml)
            map.addLayer(track)
            // Adjust map to show the kml
            const bounds = track.getBounds()
            map.fitBounds( bounds )
      });

      $('sldOpacity').on('change', function(){
   $('image-opacity').html(this.value);
   track.setStyle({opacity: this.value, fillOpacity: this.value});
 });
```

I was trying also:

```
  sldOpacity.onchange = function() {
   document.getElementById('image-opacity').innerHTML = this.value;
   track.setStyle({fillOpacity: this.value});
 }
```

but it wasn't work.

My CSS looks like this:

```
    #sldOpacity
    {
    opacity: 0.7;
    }

    #image-opacity
    {
    opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

and HTML

```
   <span id="image-opacity">0.5</span>
   <input type="range" id="sldOpacity" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5" />
```

the CSS affect the HTML range only, making it transparent, whereas the image remains still opaque.

[How to change opacity of image imported as Icon in KML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589514/how-to-change-opacity-of-image-imported-as-icon-in-kml-document)

https://jsfiddle.net/woosmap/3za64ksx/

that works for Google Maps API.

A good example is here:

But it works fine for polygons only, whereas my issue apply to image lionked in .kml file, which looks like this:

```
 <GroundOverlay>
<name>Coventry.tif</name>
<description>http://localhost/testc/Coventry.tif</description>
<Icon>
    <href>https://i.imgur.com/58CbNhB.png</href>
    <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
</Icon>
<color>55ffffff</color>
<LatLonBox>
    <north>52.39388512224325</north>
    <south>52.39299906007814</south>
    <east>-1.458241039649089</east>
    <west>-1.460061203494303</west>
</LatLonBox>
 </GroundOverlay>
```

The icon section works only in Google Earth, but not in leaflet.

Also this solution looks like sth good, but it's valid for GeoJSON file only...

[Change opacity using leaflet without plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270647/change-opacity-using-leaflet-without-plugin)

Possibly this link could bring some solution:

http://michaelminn.net/tutorials/leaflet/

but unfortunately I am not able to see the standalone map source code.

Do you have any solutions?

Thanks & Regards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this question can bring using a different KML plugin for leaflet, based in the file KML.js as per the plugin below:

https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins

where your sccript snippet should look like this:

```
  var track = new L.KML('Coventry.kml', {async: true})
.on('loaded', function (e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
})
.addTo(map);
  L.control.layers({}, {'Track':track}).addTo(map);
```

And this library recognizes an Image opacity properties set in the .XML code:

```
   <color>55ffffff</color>
```

when your image comes from the web

```
    <Icon>
<href>https://i.imgur.com/58CbNhB.png</href>
    </Icon>
```

[image]